# Get all the values for a single index in snmp

Tags: snmp

I amb reading the snmp values for a qnap nas, I have three storage with different metrics I'd like to collect, I would like to have a command to get all the values for index=1, but so far I haven't find any snmp command to accomplish it.

```
volumeID.1 = INTEGER: 1
volumeID.2 = INTEGER: 2
volumeID.3 = INTEGER: 3
volumeCapacity.1 = Counter64: 8716194508
volumeCapacity.2 = Counter64: 8716194508
volumeCapacity.3 = Counter64: 8716194508
volumeFreeSize.1 = Counter64: 3995664864
volumeFreeSize.2 = Counter64: 2783145980
volumeFreeSize.3 = Counter64: 1360632936
volumeStatus.1 = STRING: "Ready"
volumeStatus.2 = STRING: "Ready"
volumeStatus.3 = STRING: "Ready"
volumeSSDCache.1 = INTEGER: -1
volumeSSDCache.2 = INTEGER: -1
volumeSSDCache.3 = INTEGER: -1
```

I used the command below to get the output shown, but it only reads sequentialy the values I request.

```
snmpbulkget -m All  -v2c -Cn0 -Cr15 -Os -c public nas NAS-MIB::volumeID
```

This would be also useful for any non-table indexed values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While row-traversal (through the indices) is easy, you have to collect the columns (objects) explicitely, eg.

> snmpget ... volumeID.1 volumeCapacity.1 volumeFreeSize.1 ...

(and yes, you can skip the INDEX object volumeID because it's value is just it's index).